# Work flow for georeferencing imagery using open source tools?

Tags: open-source, gis, geocoding, geospatial

Does anyone have a recommendation for a work flow for georeferencing high resolution aerial photography using open source tools?  I have GPS coordinates for control points and would need to associate them with the imagery (I do not know the pixel x,y values).

Also, any open source options that can perform more sophisticated correction like orthorectification?

Thank You!

Comment: This is not programming related, and should be asked on the GIS Stack Exchange site instead: http://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: For those who are interested, User435 took Reed's suggestion and migrated his question to  gis.stackexchange. [Here's the post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/644/work-flow-for-georeferencing-imagery-using-open-source-tools)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GDAL](http://gdal.org/) privdes tools for working with imagery, including orthorectifying the images.